# linking up minipages like real pages

Tags: boxes, minipage

If I understand correctly, the main text box on a page is a special box, since in addition to the normal paragraph typesetting, text can also overflow into the next page. Is it possible to, say, have two minipages (or any sort of boxes that I can position arbitrarily in my document) so that the text in the first box that overflows gets put into the second box?

Comment: You could play around with [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol). Columns aren't too arbitrarily positioned though.

Comment: Another package to look at is [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/mdframed).

Comment: Also see `flowfram` with documentation in `ffuserguide.pdf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a lot of manual intervention it's possible, but not with the standard `minipage` environment.

A "reduced version" of TeX's page builder is available to split vertical boxes:

```
\newbox\mybigbox \newbox\mysplitbox
\setbox\mybigbox=\vbox{<material>}
\setbox\mysplitbox=\vsplit\mybigbox to 10cm
```

Now the box register `\mysplitbox` will contain 10cm high text from `\mybigbox` and `\mybigbox` will contain the rest.

Careful reading of the TeXbook or TeX by topic is necessary, as this low level mechanism has never been canned into high level macros.