# Is there a way to make a block wrap from the column 1 to the column 2?

Tags: beamer, formatting, columns, posters, block

I am formatting a poster for my thesis presentation. It is in a beamer documentclass, and I am using blocks within a column environment to split up the information so that it looks nice. I have multiple blocks in a column, and some of the text in a block will go off the bottom of the page since it is too long. Is there a way to make a block wrap around, say from the first column to the second column so that all the info is displayed? 
My other thought is to create a new block for the information that is clipped, but that would leave a fat header at the top of the block which would not be ideal. Is there another environment that I could put that info in?

Here is a link to my overleaf file if anyone wants to see the issue. https://www.overleaf.com/read/kwgqgzndspdd

Comment: is this post relevant to you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69895/95229